# Questions about creating diffraction grating

Tags: experimental-physics, diffraction, x-rays, x-ray-crystallography

I have a modern physics lab project this semester where we have to perform an experiment related to modern physics as a group of 3.

We choose https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.5020051, an undergraduate lab experiment, to imitate Rosalind Franklin's X-ray diffraction experiment.

This paper has mathematically proved that we can replace a 3d structure with its 2d flat projection for a far-field diffraction pattern. So the helix structure has been replaced by a diffraction grating of small holes arranged in a sine wave.

I have certain doubts regarding creating the grating.

1. The author of the paper suggested first plotting a sine wave using software (Here Maple), taking a printout then, putting that on black cardboard, then using a needle of appropriate radius to pierce in the cardboard at the required position. My question was how to plot such a small sine graph where the amplitude is 3.56 mm and the wavelength 11.97 mm.
2. Also, any tips on how to create the diffraction grating would be very helpful as I have no idea on how to proceed.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with plotting? Modern printers have at least 600 dpi (and usually multiple times that), which is plenty for printing a thin sine wave with the amplitude and wavelength you denoted.

Comment: Why not have a large sin wave and rhe holes adjusted to this sizee. then make a ral fim photograph  and mke this the size you want.

Comment: Every copier these days has a function to change the scale of an image. Take a large image and reduce the size four to six times by half.

Comment: Print the grating on an overhead projector transparency sheet.